# Selenium Grid UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-rc

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-37JVVAA', ip: '199.254.9.005', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: Driver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at automationFramework.Driver.startWebDriver(Driver.java:80)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{grid-selenium-hub.es-selenium-use.us-east-1.acceptance.com:4444, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=grid-selenium-hub.es-selenium-use.us-east-1.acceptance.com/12.55.42.001:4444 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:208)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)

```
{
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "custom": {
  },
  "debug": false,
  "host": "90.395.99.144",
  "jettyMaxThreads": -1,
  "newSessionRequestCount": 0,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "port": 4444,
  "registry": "org.openqa.grid.internal.DefaultGridRegistry",
  "role": "hub",
  "servlets": [
  ],
  "slotCounts": {
    "free": 10,
    "total": 10
  },
  "success": true,
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "timeout": 1800,
  "withoutServlets": [
  ]
}
```

```
Node has following:

browserTimeout: 0

debug: false

jettyMaxThreads: -1

host: 90.115.91.25:5555

port: 5555

role: node

timeout: 1800

cleanUpCycle: 5000

maxSession: 1

capabilities: Capabilities {applicationName: , browserName: chrome, maxInstances: 1, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver, server:CONFIG_UUID: 277ded26-3931-42ec-b9e6-a6b..., version: 79.0.3945.117}

downPollingLimit: 2

hub: http://selenium-grid-selenium-hub:4444/grid/register

id: http://90.115.91.25:5555

nodePolling: 5000

nodeStatusCheckTimeout: 5000

proxy: org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy

register: true

registerCycle: 5000

remoteHost: http://90.115.91.25:5555

unregisterIfStillDownAfter: 60000
```

Driver has following code

```
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
            options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
            options.addArguments("enable-automation");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
            options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
                options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
                world.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(AWS_URL), options);
world.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

```
We recently created grid on aws and see this issue for some of the pods(which is working fine earlier), though its same hub URL for all
```

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/60195709/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB Done, please help

Comment: @Kpras solved this?